# Using a HashMap for quickly looking up relationships between two entities

Tags: javascript, data-structures, hashmap, relationship, hashtable

### Tools used

Assume the language is JavaScript here, and the implementation of the HashMap is the `Map` class.

#### Data structure

Say I have a bunch of "People" objects that look similar to these two (which we will focus on), objects "John" and "Sally".

```
{
    id: "someUUID-John",
    name: "John"
}
```

```
{
    id: "someUUID-Sally",
    name: "Sally"
}
```

I also have *n* number of objects representing relationships between the above objects like so:

```
{
    id: "someRelationshipId",
    from: "someUUID-John",
    to: "someUUID-Sally",
    type: "phone_call"
}
```

The above example defines a relationship `from` John `to` Sally. Assume that there are multiple relationships going this same direction, and multiple going the other way (i.e. `from` Sally `to` John). There are also multiple relationships between other "People" objects and between both John and Sally to those other People.

#### Problem statement

The `id` of the above relationship is what this question is about.

I wish to use a `HashMap` to easily look up relationships. At the time I wish to look this up, it's safe to assume one of the two following scenarios:

- I have a reference to `John` *or* `Sally`, but **not** both
- I have a reference to *both* `John` *and* `Sally`

My question is, **A)** Is it possible to construct or use a hashing algorithm to generate a key that can be used to look up the relationship given a reference or both of the related objects and **B)** If so, what algorithm should I use or implement?

Comment: A silly solution is to compare UUID (strings are comparable, right) and assign RS only for uuid1 < uuid2. Like - some sample code can help to give you a better direction. If I need to write that code I will make a { [uuid: string]: Array<string> } and put in the key uuid and in value array (or Set) of keys and impose constrain that any key in value should be g.t. key of object.

Comment: It sounds like that's a good idea, since when I update a Relationship I will have both IDs, I should be able to update the arrays containing the relationships between both nodes. Of course, thats sort of doubling the amount of space we need to solve this problem, but its a nice and simple solution. Is there a way to do it *without* keeping two copies of what is essentially the same data?

Comment: The above stands unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying. Upon a second read, it sounds like you may be saying *not* to keep two copies (one each direction), but only one copy (outbound relationships only). If this is what you mean, unless I'm missing something, it sounds like the first use case in the problem statement above would not be met, right? I would only be able to find the outbound relationships and not the inbound ones

Comment: tbh don't see doubling of space, especially if you use set. Hope you won't OCR chines' phonebook and keep it in RAM :D

Comment: Yeah, idea is each time when you are about to add RS, you will add it to key with "lower" uuid so you will avoid duplicates.

Comment: Hmm it looks like you've lost me. Would you be able to whip up an answer with a JavaScript or pseudo code example?

Comment: I'm still not sure how we would perform a lookup of all the relationships if we only had a reference to the left side node, for example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237705/discussion-between-dragans-and-foxtrotuniform6969).